# Flutter how to change Visual Studio Code Wrap with ... order

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

VSCode offers Quick Fix feature on cmd+ shortcut. There are some Flutter shortcuts like *Wrap with*, *Swap with parent* and *remove this widget*. I don't know which plugin offers this features and this creates my question. In the past, *Wrap with widget...* option was on the top and I was satisfied with it. After some Flutter updates or installing new extensions, *wrap with* order changed. Most importantly after Bloc extension installed, my favorite option *wrap with widget...* remained at very bottom and it got harder to select it.

[image: vscode wrap with quick fix]

### What I'm Looking For

I'm looking for a setting to change the order of *quick fix* dialog.

### Feature Request

A search feature to quick fix would be great. It can be called **quickfix+** or smt like this. It'll be attached to another shortcut like *cmd+shift+.* so user will still be able to use normal quick fix. I'd like to select **Column** by writing up to **Column** letters for example **Col** (like in *cmd+shift+p*). Current quick fix still offers navigate by pressing letters but if I'm in the top image's case, I must press **Wrap with Co** to select **Wrap with column**.

[image: better quick fix]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just remembered I have posted this question. I'm using a vscode extension for a long time. It is a good workaround. Extension is called [Keyboard QuickFix](https://Name:%20Keyboard%20QuickFix%20Id:%20pascalsenn.keyboard-quickfix%20Description:%20Enables%20keyboard%20support%20for%20quickfix%20Version:%200.0.6%20Publisher:%20Pascal%20Senn%20VS%20Marketplace%20Link:%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalsenn.keyboard-quickfix).

[image: keyboard quickfix]

### Update Sep-2023

Former extension that I used is no longer performs some actions for Flutter. Maybe it's about a Flutter update or my fault. Now I use  [extension](https://Name:%20quickfixed%20Id:%20nolanderc.quickfixed%20Description:%20Allows%20using%20the%20keyboard%20in%20the%20quickfix%20menu%20Version:%200.1.0%20Publisher:%20nolanderc%20VS%20Marketplace%20Link:%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nolanderc.quickfixed) which works fine.

### ---------------

**INSTALLATION**

Download the extension from [this](https://Name:%20Keyboard%20QuickFix%20Id:%20pascalsenn.keyboard-quickfix%20Description:%20Enables%20keyboard%20support%20for%20quickfix%20Version:%200.0.6%20Publisher:%20Pascal%20Senn%20VS%20Marketplace%20Link:%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalsenn.keyboard-quickfix) link. Then attach `keyboard-quickfix.openQuickFix` shortcut on your liking. It was old quick fix shortcut `cmd+.` in my case.

[image]

Now when you call the shortcut, a searchable quickfix opens. It increases my productivity a lot.

[image: keyboard quickfix usage]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is based on the order of fixes provided by the analyzer.  File an issue on the dart-lang/sdk to get it into the analyzer queue.